# Redirection to campaigns , facebook ads page why?

Tags: facebook, redirect, ads

I appreciate you helping me with this.  I converted this facebook account/page to a business / organization type page from that of a personal type page.

When I log in to my company facebook account to administer it, it brings me to a facebook ads campaign page. It shows a list of ads we once used, however we deleted the ads account.

If I want to create a NEW FB app by following: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ and I click this http://developers.facebook.com/apps  instead of asking me for Developer Access - it is redirecting me to a campaigns page. How can I fix this, and or why is this happening?

I deleted my facebook ads account so I am not sure why this is still showing. I would like to just go to the main FB page and edit as any other page.

Thank You

Comment: No, this is NOT offtopic, Will. In fact, the answer is very helpful to me, a developer!

Answer (score 2):

'Business' accounts can't create apps - you need to do this from a real, regular, verified profile - then link the new app to the advertising account via the app settings (advertising accounts under Advanced)